# In pyautogui, "while True:" is not doing right in my code

Tags: pyautogui

```
import pyautogui as pag
import time
import keyboard

print("press 'p' to stop checking your mouse position")

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(pag.position())
    
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("Checked your position?\n")
        break

x, y = input("input position(x y): ").split()
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
pag.moveTo(x, y, 2) 

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    pag.click(button='left')

    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        print("End\n")
        break

print("Thank you for using ^.^")
time.sleep(0.3)
```

In while True: it does not re-do my words. It only activates once before if keyboard~.
I wonder why it is not working

```
while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(pag.position())
```

works well. but if I put more words with if ~, It does not works.
Help me..

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that keyboard.read_key() only reads the next pressed key and blocks the program until a key is pressed. This means that the loop cannot continue until a key is pressed, which is why the additional words are not being printed.

To fix this, you can use keyboard.is_pressed(key) instead, which checks whether a key is currently being pressed without blocking the program. Here is an updated version of your code that should work:

```py
import pyautogui as pag
import time
import keyboard

print("Press 'p' to stop checking your mouse position")

while True:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(pag.position())
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        print("Checked your position?\n")
        break

x, y = input("Input position (x y): ").split()
x = int(x)
y = int(y)
pag.moveTo(x, y, 2) 

while True:
    time.sleep(0.1) 
    pag.click(button='left')

    if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
        print("End\n")
        break

print("Thank you for using ^.^")
time.sleep(0.3)
```

Note that you should also update the prompt message to reflect the fact that the program will stop when the key is pressed, not when it is released.